# How to use a key from source JSON as a value in the output using JSONata?

Tags: mapping, key-value, jsonata

I have JSON data where the keys are dynamic and I want to use these keys as values in my output.

For example, consider the following JSON as source:

```
{
  "skills":{
    "Axel":[
      "MSOffice",
      "SQL",
      "Photoshop"
    ],
    "Ronda":[
      "Googledocs",
      "VBA",
      "Figma"
    ]
  }
}
```

In the above example, the names "Axel" and "Ronda" are dynamic. How do I output this data to be like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Axel",
    "skills": [
      "MSOffice",
      "SQL",
      "Photoshop"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Ronda",
    "skills": [
      "Googledocs",
      "VBA",
      "Figma"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $keys and $lookup functions to build it:

```
$keys(skills).{
  "name": $,
  "skills": $lookup($$.skills, $)
}
```

See it live: https://stedi.link/Wf3GAgR